# Install extension for Magento 2 in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, web-development-server

I', trying to install a Magento extension in My magento version 1.9.2.4 , the company provide this extension send to me the package and command line to execute and create the module , i tried run these command by ssh , but there are no existence for `bin/magento` folder in all my structure , please advice what i have to replace the `bin/magento` in all my command and where i suppose to be in which folder to execute these commands .

```
ex. php -f bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Aramex_Adminhtml
```

the result is could not open input file bin/magento .

Comment: bin/magento is available in magento 2. Its not available in magento 1. You need magento 1 extrension

Comment: this extension is compatible with magento 1.9 but aramex don't give me another package m is there any way to install this extension ?

Comment: than you don't need to execute this command. Just install magento 1 extension package and follow magento 1 installation steps.

Comment: Magento 1 not need to run any command for extension instalation. Verify that you get proper package or not.

Answer (score 0):

Typical magento 1 installation looks like

- Backup store files and the store database.
- Disable compilation mode in System > Tools > Compilation.
- disable Magento cache – Cache Management
- Log out from magento admin panel ( if you logged in )
- Unzip extension package
- Upload content of package to your magento root directory.

  - package/app >> magento_root/app
  - package/skin >> magento_root/skin
  - and so on
- configure the extension
- enable cache / compilation

Magento 1 does not have console tool like magento 2. Besides, magento 2 extension can not be compatible magento 1. They have different codebase. You need to push your extension provider to give you correct extension.

Answer (score -1):

If I got the title correctly, you can't install a Magento 2 extension on Magento 1.9